# How to detect a multiple-bar pattern?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, template-matching

**I'd like to detect a custom "multiple-bar pattern" in an image.**

The pattern looks like this, kind of a group of parallel **black** bars with the same width but different height, see this image:

[image: image 1]

This pattern could be on the image or even not but if it is - I'd like to get it's position.

**Note**: The color of the pattern is **black** in every case.

**Note**: The size of the pattern is unknown, so it could be big or could be super small.

**Note**: The pattern bar count is a fixed number. It will be the same ( in this case 7) for every occurrence.

---

An image could look like this:

[image]

And after performing the code search algorithm this should happen:

[image]

---

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks a million in advance, Tempi.

**Note**: The code I got so far *(not working)*

```
Mat myImage; // this is the mat of the photo you can see above
Mat algorithmImage;
myImage.coptyTo(algorithmImage); 
cvtColor(algorithmImage, algorithmImage, CV_RGB2HSV);

double imgThreshold = 20;
cv::inRange(algorithmImage, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0, 0), cv::Scalar(180, 255, 30, 0), 20);

Mat canny;
vector<vector<Point>> contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

Canny( algorithmImage, canny, 3, 6, 3 );
findContours( canny, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );

for( int i = 0; i<contours.size(); i++ ) {
  // ??
}

bool isLineAlreadyFound(const Vec4i& _l1, const Vec4i& _l2) {
    Vec4i l1(_l1), l2(_l2);

    float length1 = sqrtf((l1[2] - l1[0])*(l1[2] - l1[0]) + (l1[3] - l1[1])*(l1[3] - l1[1]));
    float length2 = sqrtf((l2[2] - l2[0])*(l2[2] - l2[0]) + (l2[3] - l2[1])*(l2[3] - l2[1]));

    float product = (l1[2] - l1[0])*(l2[2] - l2[0]) + (l1[3] - l1[1])*(l2[3] - l2[1]);

    if (fabs(product / (length1 * length2)) < cos(CV_PI / 30))
        return false;

    float mx1 = (l1[0] + l1[2]) * 0.5f;
    float mx2 = (l2[0] + l2[2]) * 0.5f;

    float my1 = (l1[1] + l1[3]) * 0.5f;
    float my2 = (l2[1] + l2[3]) * 0.5f;
    float dist = sqrtf((mx1 - mx2)*(mx1 - mx2) + (my1 - my2)*(my1 - my2));

    if (dist > std::max(length1, length2) * 0.5f)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Arbitrary size and rotation makes this a hard problem.  Are there a specific set of rotations, like multiples of 45 degrees?

Comment: @stark: Not at all. This isn't a C++ problem, of course. In pattern recognition, it's trivial.

Comment: Trivial? Yet 3 radically different answers.  None of which suggest how to identify which is the top or bottom of the resulting pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would approach your problem.

- Since your pattern is totally black, may be you can benefit from that
  and just do a threshold. Try a very low threshold (if it's a perfect
  black, use 1 as a threshold).
- After above step, using findContours should already do a good job in
  detecting shapes. But what you'll need is a way to **recognize** your
  pattern. Since you your patterns may show up in different scale and/or
  orientation, you will need a scale/orientation invariant descriptor. I
  mean here, a shape descriptor. You can look at
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment for Hu moments.
- That will be for only one bar in each pattern. You should complete
  your search by designing a specific feature for your pattern with the
  help of the features extracted from each bar.

Answer (score 0):

Th trick here is that you have 14 parallel edges. Those are impossible to miss. As noted in other answer, threshold to isolate them. Directly after that, run the edge detector. This turns black&white edges into lines, while the rest of the image might produce a few scattered pixels. Visualize this to see for yourself.

Next, run the Hough Transform from OpenCV. This gives you lines in the format {offset, direction}. Even if a few scattered background pixels would coincidentally line up, they wouldn't form 14 lines with the same direction.

You can calculate the maximum offset difference to find the scale of the bar pattern, and double-check the relative offsets to check individual bar widths and spacings. Remember, the 14 lines are edges, so you need to pair them.

At this point you've identified the direction and scale of the bar pattern. it might be a bit surprising to realize you haven't actually identified the actual bar positions. The reason for this procedure is that we tackle the hard problem first. We now go back to the output of the edge detection, and divide all the edges there into three categories: the parallel edges, the rounded end caps between two pairs of parallel edges (follow the contours), and random background pixels. You might need a `MORPH_CLOSE` operation to close gaps in the contour.